# Failed - network error when downloading excel file made by EPPlus.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I try to download an excel file made by `EPPlus.dll` from an asp.net c# web form application. but i get Failed - network error.
It should be noted that mentioned error just occurs in chrome and the job can be done successfully in another browsers.

by the way this error does not occure on my localhost and it happens only on the main server.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

http://www.irandnn.ir/blog/PostId/29/epplus

Comment: post the code for the click event or something where this file is being actually sent to the client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage())
{
    //Code to fill Excel file with data.


    Byte[] bin = p.GetAsByteArray();

    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", Nombre_Del_Libro + ".xlsx"));
    Response.BinaryWrite(bin);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: When i set extension to ".xlsx" , its not getting opened in Excel(2016) on development environment. When i change it to ".xlx", it working. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem when I was using Response.Clear() and Response.Close() and had to avoid them to look my code as below which is working.

```
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nameOfFile);
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.End();
```

Comment: Strange it had been working on my site with clear and close, then suddenly I started getting this error.  Using End seems to have fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer not use response.End() because throw an exception

```
    protected void DownloadFile(FileInfo downloadFile, string downloadFilename, string downloadContentType)
    {
        Byte[] bin = File.ReadAllBytes(downloadFile.FullName); 

        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = downloadContentType;
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", downloadFilename ));
        Response.BinaryWrite(bin);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.SuppressContent = true; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved with the code below, note the quotes in filename=\"Name.xlsx\":

```
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Name.xlsx\"");
//Writeout the Content  
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am exporting html table code which is in string variable HTML

Following Code Working For Me

```
byte[] myFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HTML);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/excel");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0};", "BAGrowthReport.xls"));
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", myFile.Length.ToString()); //Here is the additional header which is required for Chrome.
        Response.BinaryWrite(myFile);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
```