# EPPLus - export to Excel returns failed-network error

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, epplus

In my ASP.NET Core 1.1 app, I am exporting data to Excel using [EPPLus.Core](https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core). But at the time of File download I get the error: `Failed- network error`

**Controller**

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> CPT_RC_Excel(int FiscalYear)
{
    var custlist = _Context.Customers.Where(c => c.Region=="NW").ToList();

  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(ms))
  {
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Clients");
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(custlist);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=TestFile.xlsx");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    var bytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();
    await Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return File(ms, "application/force-download", "TestFile.xlsx");
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

1. Error occurs on both `Google Chrome and IE 11`. The entire app is on a local desktop. No network drive is involved here.
2. Error does seem to be related to the code above since another action method (code shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44294552/1232087)) in the same controller does down load the csv/text files successfully.

Comment: Check this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617706/failed-network-error-when-downloading-excel-file-made-by-epplus-dll

Comment: @sQanns I had checked that first. But `VS2015` does not recognize the following commands mentioned in the accepted answer there: `Response.ClearHeaders();   Response.ClearContent(); Response.BinaryWrite(bin); Response.Flush();  Response.End();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CPT_RC_Excel(int FiscalYear)
        {

            var fileContentAsByteArray = [generate your file as a byte array]

            return File(fileContentAsByteArray, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "TestFile.xlsx");

        }
```

if this doesn't work then the issue is with the file generation.

try removing the reference to the MemoryStream and use...

```
...
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
{
...
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggested solution but still the exact same error.

Comment: I think your suggestion makes sense. But probably I'm not following it correctly as you're expecting. Could you please copy/paste my code in your response and modify it to what you're suggesting? Thank you.

Comment: Are you suggesting to remove `MemoryStream`, `Response` objects etc, and instead try your `using{...}` block with `var fileContentAsByteArray = excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();` and `return File(fileContentAsByteArray,..........)`?

Comment: Yes, remove the memorystream

Comment: I performed the steps mentioned in my previous comment - and it worked. Thank you for your suggestions.